# Wording improvement for the Create Tag Synonyms help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-center

The [Create Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) page, under the section "How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?", contains the paragraph

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

The thing to note here is that the clarification in parenthesis, "total upvotes minus total downvotes", comes after the 2nd occurrence of the phrase it tries to clarify, "a total answer score". Instead, the clarification should appear always after the 1st occurrence of the phrase:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.